# PowerShell error R6016

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

I'm currently creating a powershell script dedicated to install some softs for my job.

The script will call a cmd that calls a ps1 that will install (or uninstall) the software.

However, on some of the computers that uses my script, it gets the following error :

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!

Program: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

R6016
- not enough space for thread data
```

Looking for this error on the internet, I found the following link :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126709

It says :

> Spawning and closing an application repeatedly succeeds around 60
>   times, then the spawn fails with this error: R6016 - not enough space
>   for thread data

Indeed, sometimes when I try to make around 60 install / uninstall using my script, I get this error.

But I don't understand how I could apply the resolution : what is Win32s ? How could I free the "TLS" ?

Is there something I should do when I spawn or exit a PowerShell ? Is it because a cmd is always calling a ps1 ?

> EDIT :

I finally found how to generate the error with a simple line of code from a cmd :

`powershell -noprofile -command "[Environment]::Exit($host.version.major)"`

This should give me with an "echo %errorlevel%" the major version of PowerShell (usually 3,4,5) and sometimes, it gives me "255" and this event "R6016" inserted in the event viewer System.

Thank you to anyone who can help me solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly is the script doing?

Comment: Win32S was a set of libraries that allowed some 32bit applications to run on 16 bit Windows 3.1. This won't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Sean : indeed, but this is the only article from Microsoft about this problem, so that's my only idea for now :(

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : I added a line of code that produced the problem.